# Why do we add the positive clock skew to the minimum clock period?

Tags: flipflop, time, skew

Given the following circuit: [image]

I was told that the minimum clock period would be the sum of the setup time plus the propagation delay plus the clock skew for a positive clock skew. I was wondering as to why we add the clock skew to the time period when it is positive because a positive clock skew would only decrease the time the value of QA can be held. Don't we just have to check if the propagation delay is greater than the hold time plus the time skew? How does adding the clock skew solve any issues?

Comment: I guess it comes down to what you mean by positive clock skew.  In your picture is it Tcb-Tca, or Tca-Tcb?  That is, one of your two clocks (or a 3rd?) has to be you reference from which the skew to the other is measured.

Comment: And what do you mean by propagation delay?  Is it just the prop time of QA along the trace?  Or does that include the clk->Q delay of the first flip flop?

Comment: By positive clock skew, I mean positive when Tcb-Tca is positive. By propagation delay, I mean both the combined delays of the prop time of QA along the trace and the clk->Q delay of the first flip flop.